# std::set, функция сравнения

Tags: c++

Имеется следующая структура данных:

```
std::vector< std::set<unsigned> > G;
```

и класс для сравнения:

```
struct classcomp{

unsigned *ia;
bool operator() (const int& a, const int& b) const
{
    return (ia[a + 1] - ia[a])< (ia[b + 1] - ia[b]);
} };
```

Что бы сравнивать этим классом необходимо создать экземпляр класса:

```
classcomp C;
C.ia = ia;
```

Но создать тогда

```
std::vector< std::set<unsigned,C> > G;
```

нельзя, тк вторым параметром требуется имя класса, а не его экземпляр. Подскажите как обойти этот момент.

Comment: А в чём конкретно проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно, в шаблоне надо указывать тип:

```
std::vector<std::set<unsigned, classcomp>> G;
```

При добавлении элементов надо использовать конструктор, принимающий компаратор

```
G.emplace_back(C);
```

При этом у `std::set<unsigned, classcomp>` нельзя использовать конструктор по умолчанию, по этому например нельзя вызывать `G.resize(n);`, вместо этого надо использовать

```
G.resize(n, std::set<unsigned, classcomp>(C));
```

Comment: Видимо вопрос уже не по теме: когда второй раз вставляется элемент в `G[i]` , те как раз происходит обращение к компаратору, то вылетает ошибка права доступа.

Comment: @Евгений почему вы минусанули ответ? Он ведь правильный, или вам требуется, чтобы тип экземпляра класса компаратора вычислялся автоматически? Тогда если имеете доступ к _C++11_, то воспользуйтесь `decltype`: `std::vector<std::set<unsigned, decltype(C)>> G;`

Comment: @StateItPrimitive я и не думал минусовать ответ, наоборот хотел плюс поставить. С чего вы взяли, что я заминусовал?

Comment: @Евгений "Додумал", извиняюсь. Вы бы не могли привести минимальный полный код, который генерирует ранее описанную ошибку доступа, чтобы вам смогли быстрее помочь? Если это не относится напрямую к вопросу, то пример такого кода можете разместить вот [здесь](https://ideone.com/), а затем дать нам ссылочку, либо оформить новый вопрос.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive ничего страшного)  добавил в основное сообщение

Comment: `resize` вызывать можно. Надо только использовать соответствующую перегрузку, которая принимает значение-образец.